# Bad substitution running MongoDB commands in linux shell

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a simple bash script to test the return value of a MongoDB query. The Mongo script itself returns the expected value. But, if I try to put the query script into ${}, I get a **"Bad substitution"** error. Any ideas ?

```
#!/bin/bash

#This line returns the number 1 (expected value)
mongo dbName --eval 'db.dbCollection.find({"updatedAt":{"$gt":ISODate("2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")}}).count()'

#Trying run from inside a "${}" returns the error
counter=${"mongo dbName --eval db.dbColection.find({'updatedAt':{'$gt':ISODate('2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z')}}).count()"}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. This line returns the expected value to the var:

```
counter=$(mongo dbName --eval 'db.dbCollection.find({"updatedAt":{"$gt":ISODate("2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")}}).count()')
```

In other words, I surrounded the Mongo commands with simple quotes and used the double quotes inside the command. And, instead of curly braces, I'm using parentheses. That's it !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
counter=$(mongo dbName --eval db.dbColection.find({'updatedAt':{'$gt':ISODate('2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z')}}).count()")
```

Comment: Thank you @funkyjelly, but I got an error: unexpected EOF found while looking for  `"'